# Copy Files from NFS or Local FS to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs, distributed-system, distcp

I am trying to copy large number of files (100k+, total size 2 TB) from NFS to HDFS. What is the efficient way to do it.

I have tried below options after mounting it to edge node

1. hdfs dfs -put : It fails with memory error and transfer is also slow
2. distcp : Getting Error Caused by:

   > org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand$CopyReadException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

However the file exists.

I have tried the same on a local file without using NFS mounted location.
I was aware of one of the caveat for distcp is, the destination has to be distributed. Does it apply for source as well? Or its a bug and have workaround for this ?

distcp command:

```
hadoop distcp file:/home/<user>/t1/f1.dat hdfs://<hdfs-ip>:8020/user/<user>/t1
```

Error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand$CopyReadException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/<user>/t1/f1.dat does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.CopyMapper.map(CopyMapper.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:796)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:169)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.tools.mapred.RetriableFileCopyCommand$CopyReadException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/<user>/t1/f1.dat does not exist
        ... 10 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify file system properly, i.e. "file:///home/<user>/..."?

Comment: @mazaneicha yes, same error

Comment: And I assume you checked the permissions?

Comment: @mazaneicha yes, to be double sure i retried after full permission but no luck

Comment: And you have this local file accessible from all cluster nodes?

Comment: @mazaneicha I also think this is the issue. How to check or make it accessible?

Comment: Try `head` or `cat` a file from every worker node. For NFS make sure it is mounted and use the same mount point, for local file -- that its been copied to all nodes.

Comment: @mazaneicha That means both source should be distributed to distcp to work.

Comment: Either distributed (if using local FS) or shared (in case of NFS). By nature, `distcp` starts a mapred job on the cluster, so every `CopyMapper` needs to have access to the file.

Comment: If that doesnt work for you, try to increase hdfs client memory. Take a look at SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405690/out-of-memory-issue-for-hadoop-copyfromlocal for example.

Comment: @mazaneicha justified, you can post this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `distcp` to work, local file should be accessible from all worker nodes within a cluster, either via mount points on every node to access shared NFS location, or by physically copying it to local file system of every node.

Alternatively, `hdfs dfs -put` (or `-copyFromLocal`) could still work if you increase the heap size of hadoop client:

```
$ export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-DXmx4096m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
```

But as you said, the transfer will be slower compared to distcp.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the property in core-site.xml to mount an hdfs path onto a local directory as NFS and then copying the files from your NFS to this path

dfs.nfs3.export.point=[your hdfs path]